# SymmetricDS 3.12 to connect to Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle12c, symmetricds

I'm trying to start a one-way replication using SymmetricDS btw two oracle servers (Master to Slave). The version I'm using for Symmetric is 3.12 to connect to Oracle 12c.
Checking the lib directory I found the JDBC Oracle version 8 (ojdbc8-18.3.0.0.jar), but to right driver to connect to Oracle 12c version 7 (ojdbc7.jar).

I would like to know if I'm right on my assumption and, if yes, how can I set SymmetricDS to use ojdbc7.jar?

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, you should be able to switch out the driver with a newer one.  You would just have to remove the old from the lib directory and drop the new one in.

However, the JDBC driver that comes with SymmetricDS works just fine for Oracle 12c.  I would stick with it because it is well tested.